# What is this song playing in The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead, music-identification

What is the song playing in *The Walking Dead* season 2 episode 5 (when Daryl pulls the arrow out) and in season 3 episode 10 (when Daryl and Merle help the Mexicans)? It's also in the game *The Walking Dead: Survival instinct*. It has a "redneck" feeling in it.

Comment: there isn't any music playing during those scenes... are you sure of the particulars?

Comment: Yeah it is :P And it's been haunting me since that season two episode x3 maybe not exactly when he pulls it out but during that part of the episode, when he cuts the ears off and stuff :P

Comment: http://vimeo.com/60151138 here's one of the episodes you mentioned... give me a time code where the music starts and we'll see what we can do

Comment: 21:50 it starts ^^

Comment: on season 2 episode 5 it starts at 26:12, that one feels a bit more speeded up tho, but the same music

Comment: I figured it out... we were just having a terminology problem. Confusion has cleared and hopefully my answer will clear it up for you too :)

Answer (score 6):

What you are talking about is not a song, but rather a musical cue. See, the Walking Dead is scored by one [Bear McCreary](http://www.bearmccreary.com/#). The only possible name that I could find for it comes from this [forum post](http://www.bearmccreary.com/forum//viewtopic.php?f=15&t=27&start=10) which refers to it as Daryls theme/Dream tones. Luckily, he wrote a whole [blog post](http://www.bearmccreary.com/#blog/the-walking-dead/the-walking-dead-chupacabra/) talking about what he was hoping to accomplish and embedded a nice video showing how he came up with the sounds you heard.

However, that particular piece of music hasn't been rerecorded anywhere I could find, so I can't link you to a place to buy it. Of course, it's not the only place he uses those tribal style drums in his music, so if you cruise through some more of his work, you will probably find some stuff that speaks to you just as much!